# angular-ui bootstrap tabs reorder orderBy

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular and [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) tabs.  I would live to use the orderBy or be able to dynamically reorder the tabs.

I created this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zre1MUaqLP8CLnD17CIL?p=preview)

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs | orderBy:disabled" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the quotes. Basically the field name is string and it requires the quotes.

Try this

```
ng-repeat="tab in tabs | orderBy:'disabled'"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax error.  I tried that in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zre1MUaqLP8CLnD17CIL), and it still doesn't order the tabs.